# how to transpose the results of a query in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a query (below) that returns a table (below) and I'm looking to transpose the table so that the dates are the column names and the column names are converted into the first column. I've seen crosstab be suggested a lot but after reading the documentation it doesn't seem suitable for this kind of query. Maybe I'm wrong?

```
   select 
    temp."Date", total_pass, total_fail, total_IR,
    total_committed, total-total_committed as total_uncommitted, total
    from (select date_trunc('month', application.created) as "Date",
           sum((status = 'pass')::int) as total_pass,
           sum((status = 'fail')::int) as total_fail,
           sum((status = 'internal_review')::int) 
           - sum((type = 'internal_review')::int) as total_IR,
           sum((status = 'pass')::int)+sum((status = 'fail')::int)+sum((status = 'internal_review')::int) 
           -sum((type = 'internal_review')::int) as total_committed
    from application
    where application.job_status != 'expired' 
          and date_trunc('month', application.created) > 'now'::timestamp - '2 month'::interval
    group by "Date") temp 
    
    left join 
      (select date_trunc('month', users.created) as "Date", count(*) as total
      from users
      where users.enabled = true 
      and date_trunc('month', users.created) > 'now'::timestamp - '2 month'::interval
      group by date_trunc('month', users.created)) temp2
    on temp."Date"=temp2."Date"
    
    order by "Date"
```

| Date | total_pass | total_fail | total_ir | total_commmitted | total_uncommitted | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| June 1, 2021 | 146 | 22 | 22 | 190 | 157 | 347 |
| July 1, 2021 | 183 | 19 | 46 | 248 | 180 | 428 |

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `sum((status = 'pass')::int)` can also be written as `count(*) filter (where status = 'pass')` - much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @Bergi this is all the code, it's pulling from 2 separate tables one and it wouldn't make sense to transpose those 2 tables if that's what you're suggesting?